# How to prevent window borders to cross the desktop edges on Kwin?

Tags: linux, desktop

I'm currently working on a profesional program, and I need to configure windows for they cannot go over the limit of the desktop (so they will always be visible, whatever move you apply to them). I use Kwin 3 and 4. I know this is not a very common feature, but this is crucial for this program. Does someone know the way to configure this functionality ? Thanks !

Comment: Don't do that. Some users might not want your app window to stay always on top. Respect the freedom of your users.

Comment: You do not talk about my problem : I do not speak about the management of window priority, but about the prevention for a window to be not fully visible due to a placement on the edge of the desktop. Furthermore, this feature was required by the client itself - and it is an exclusive client -, and has been implemented for more than 10 years in the previous version.So there is no liberty restriction...

Comment: Ok, I found the answer on another forum : go into your HOME/.kde/share/config/kwinrc, and set BorderSnap to 10000, and SnapOnlyWhenOverlapping to true.